# DevEx grid control auto calculate column and label C# code and entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am using dev express grid control. I wanted to auto calculate the `score` column and the label and display it in `Grade` column....The "score" is editable while the label is fixed already!!!

Formula:

`Label + (score) = Grade column`

Answer (score 0):

You didn't promote any code.

But mabye the help of devexpress is for you [click me](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument753)

There you can find something like this.

```
string cellValue;
cellValue = gridView1.GetRowCellValue(2, "ID").ToString()
```

My codesample would be

```
int cellValueScore;
string cellValueLabel;

cellValueScore = gridView1.GetRowCellValue(2, "score");
cellValue = gridView1.GetRowCellValue(2, "Label").ToString();

return cellValueLabel + cellValueScore.ToString();
```